# How to connect MAMP based MYSQL in Python?

Tags: python-2.7, mamp, mysql-python

I recently upgraded Python on my Macbook to 2.7 via Macport and eventually I had to upgrade MySQL driver too. I tried to install it via Macport but that guy installed another copy of MySQL server too. I want to use MAMP based MYSQL in Python. On connection I am getting error:

**_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock'**

How do I point it out to MAMP based MySQL?

Thanks

Comment: What arguments are you supplying to `connect()`?